# How can I host an SSL Rest API through AWS using a Docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I've gotten a bit lost in the number of services in AWS and I'm having a difficult time finding the answer to what I think is probably a very simple question.

I have a Docker image that's serving a RestAPI over HTTP on port 80. I am currently hosting this on AWS with ECS. It's using Faregate but I could make an EC2 cluster if need be.

The problems are:
1) I currently get a new IP address whenever I run my task, I want a consistent address to access it from. Doesn't need to be a static IP, it could be routed from DNS.
2) It's not using my hostname which I would like to have api.myhostname.com go to the Docker image while www.myhostname.com currently already goes to my Cloudfront CDN serving the web application.
3) There's no SSL and I would need this to be encrypted.

Which services should I be using to make this happen? I looked into API Gateways and didn't find a way to use an ECS task as a backend. I looked into ELB for ECS but load balancers didn't seem to provide a way to make static IPs out of the Docker images.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a static IP? I ask this because my first impression was that an ALB fits perfectly into your use case (solves the SSL issue and allows to use your hostname by redirecting it to the load balancer DNS name) but then I read the static IP address requirement... which is pretty uncool in AWS... Also there is another question: Do you need a public or a private static IP??

Comment: I don't need a static IP at all, actually. I just need a consistent address to always access my API, regardless of how many times its spun down or started up. So I'll edit the question with that updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll suggest a service for each of you requirements:

1. you want to run a Docker container: ECS using FARGATE is the right solution
2. you want a consistent address: use the Service Load Balancing which is integrated into ECS. [1] You can also achieve consistent addressing using Service Discovery if the price for running a load balancer is too high in your scenario. [2]
3. you want SSL: AWS Elastic Load Balancing integrates with AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) which allows you to create HTTPS listeners. [3]
4. you want to use your hostname: use AWS Route53 and an Application Load Balancer. The load balancer receives a hostname by aws automatically and you can then point your custom dns at that entry. [4]

So my advice is:

- Create an ECS service which starts your docker container as FARGATE task.
- Create a certificate for your HTTPS listener in AWS Certificate Manager. ACM manages your certificates and sends you an email if they are expiring soon. [5]
- Use Service Load Balancing with an Application Load Balancer to automatically register any newly created ECS tasks to a target group. Configure the load balancer to listen for incoming traffic on an HTTPS listener and routes it to the target group which has your ECS tasks registered as targets.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-service-discovery.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html
[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to grind away at this tomorrow, leave comments on how it went, and I suppose likely mark this as the correct answer assuming everything goes to plan.

Comment: Looking forward to provide you some more references if you need more guidance. =)

Comment: This has been really great information so far, thank you. I'm having difficulty with with following the instruction "Use Service Load Balanacing with an Application Load Balancer to automatically register any newly created ECS tasks" When I created an target group for my ALB I was allowed to pick an EC2 instance, or IP address, or Lambda function for my target type for the new target group. Registering targets only allowed me to select from my EC2 instances. How do I register ECS tasks to my target group?

Comment: Oh hm, I found this... https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-alb-auto-register/ I didn't realize I needed to create an ECS service in order to register the tasks to the target group.

Comment: Yes that ist correct. You need an ECS service for this to work.

Comment: Okay so I've set things up the way you described. I have an ALB with a target group that is registering targets from an ECS instance. The targets popped up in the target group as expected. However, I'm trying to test this and I'm going to the URL listed in the DNS Name field of my ALB's description. I figure I should be able to go there with HTTPS on port 443 (so basically https://that-url in my browser) and get a response from my Docker image's RESTApi. It's timing out however. I never get a response from that URL. I haven't tried yet to use my own domain.

Comment: There are two reasons why this is happening: 
1. Do you route the traffic to the correct port? Which is the port which is used for the container and which is the port which is displayed for the registered target in the ALB's target group.
2. Did you set up the security group for the ALB and for the ECS task correctly? It depends on the task's networking mode how to configure the latter one. Which is your task networking mode?

Comment: Hm... that was helpful. I didn't have the correct security group setup. I'm still not done but would like to say thanks for all the help responding. Hopefully this comment log will help someone else someday too. But now.. I'm getting an error 503 "service temporarily unavailable" for an hour now so I'd say it's not really temporary. When I went to the URL with https, I got a warning from chrome that it was not secure and I needed to click advanced to proceed. Chrome now shows a "not secure" message in the URL with the body of the page being the 503 error.

Comment: Are you using https at the service in your docker container? The ALB performs SSL termination. That ist why a plain HTTP connection to the backen d is sufficient.

Comment: I have plain http in my docker. Perhaps the issue is that I'm using the certificate from my domain (which was the only option available) but I am actually accessing it via an amazon.com DNS name? Like I said I haven't done the custom domain name aspect. In fact I realize I might not need to. Is am wondering now, though, why isn't there an option to use an Amazon cert for their domain?

Comment: The hostname which is assigned to your certificate must match the one you enter into the browser. If you want to use a custom domain name, you have to redirect it to the ALB's domain name using a Route53 alias record or a CNAME record (if you use a custom DNS provider).

Comment: Amazingly I'm still stuck. I have a task and cluster in ECS for my Docker which serves on 80 which works fine. The security group I'm using for that is that same as the service which serves over 80. I have a load balancer with listener on 443 and it's set to forward to my target group. My target group's port is 80. When I create the service, I chose my existing target group and the only option for "Production listener port" in the "Container to load balance" section is a 443 listener. I feel confused by this. I think it should be 80. That's what my task is and that's what the target group is.

Comment: Wow okay I figured it out. The above comment I made isn't a problem. Though a tad confusing as stated above, it's fine that way. My real problem was that when I setup the Application Load Balancer, I was automatically encouraged to use the default security group, which allows no inbound traffic. I have now created a new security group for it which permits HTTPS inbound on 443. The service now works. Thank you for all your help. If you, someone else, are reading this in the future, I my struggling comment thread does you some good.

Comment: Thanks for the Service Discovery tip. More painless than I expected!